# sessionStorage returns undefined

Tags: jquery, typescript, kendo-grid, session-storage

I have clientside application that is using sessionStorage to move data from one view to another. my code is:

```
$("#reportGrid").find("input:checked").each(function () {
    rows.push($(this).closest('tr'));

    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    console.log("TicketNumber => " + dataItem.ticketNumber + " " + dataItem.lineNumber);

    // store dataItem in session Storage;
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedRecords', JSON.stringify(dataItem));
    var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedRecords'));

    console.log("Begin -----------");
    console.log("userSelectedRecords => " + retrievedObject[0].ticketNumber);
    console.log("End -----------");
})
```

However, the line `console.log("userSelectedRecords => " + retrievedObject[0].ticketNumber);`  returns

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticketNumber' of undefined

How can I display the data from previous view?

Comment: So that means `dataItem` is undefined, so the line above it is not working...

Comment: The line "console.log("TicketNumber => " + dataItem.ticketNumber + " " + dataItem.lineNumber);" displays correct data

Comment: In your question, you are saying it throws an error....

Comment: sorry.... typo. Fixed it

Comment: Okay so that means `retrievedObject[0]` is undefined... Why are you reading it as an array? Do you think it is an array?

Comment: Why set and then immediately retrieve the item? You also treat it like an object earlier in the code but like an array later in the code. `dataItem.ticketNumber` vs `retrievedObject[0].ticketNumber`

Comment: You are serializing an individual item, then trying to access it as an array.  `retrievedObject.ticketNumber` should work.

Comment: I would do a `console.log` on `retrievedObject` to see what it is and how to access its contents.

Comment: @SteveCampbell, that worked. Thanks. Post that as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Meeseeks console.log on retrievedObject returns [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your code you want to loop through an array of items and grab all of the ones that are checked. Currently you are looping over the checked items and storing each one into a session variable and you keep writing over it. When you read it, you only will ever have one item. If that is what you want, than you just need to reference the object, not do an array syntax.

```
console.log("userSelectedRecords => " + retrievedObject.ticketNumber);
```

BUT I do not think that is what you want to do. I think you want to have an array of elements that the user selected. To have an array, you need to build up the list and than save the whole array when the loop is finished.

```
//temp holding place for the data
var records = [];    
$("#reportGrid").find("input:checked").each(function () {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    records.push(dataItem);  //push the element
});
//save it to localstorage
sessionStorage.setItem('selectedRecords', JSON.stringify(records));

//now your syntax would work
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedRecords'));
if (retrievedObject.length) { //make sure we have at least one item
    console.log("userSelectedRecords => " + retrievedObject[0].ticketNumber);
}
```

Comment: well, my intention is to pass a grid row (or rows) as selected by the user, from one MVVM view to another view (in old school webpages, I would use session objects). I will try out your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: yes, the user will select one or more rows. So I need an array.